# Java Android Check if e-mail already exists on firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to create a logging activity for my app. So I used firebase. But now I want to make a toast that says when I insert an already existing email but I'm finding it difficult to do so. This is what I did:

```
 public void checkEmailExistsOrNot(){

    fAuth.fetchSignInMethodsForEmail(eml).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<SignInMethodQueryResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<SignInMethodQueryResult> task) {
            if (task.getResult().getSignInMethods().size() == 0){
                exist = false;
            }else {
                exist = true;
            }

        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
}
```

Here I check if the boolean is equal to true (therefore the email already exists and I do not continue with the registration) or if it is alse, the email does not exist, so I proceed with the registration:

```
  checkEmailExistsOrNot();

    if (exist) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Email giá registrata", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        return;
    } else {

        fAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(eml, passw).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "registration made", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "registration not performed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

The problem is that even when I insert already existing emails, the exist variable still remains false so the program tries to create an account, failing to do so, it brings up a toast that says registration not performed. How can I solve?

full code: https://codeshare.io/5QPeNL

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java Android Check if e-mail already exists on a firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67734451/java-android-check-if-e-mail-already-exists-on-a-firebase)

Comment: If your question is closed and marked 'Duplicate', the goal is not for you to duplicate it yet again, but to check the original question to find the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase automatically tells you if an email that you want to create an account with already exists.
When creating an account you should check if the task was succesfull and under

```
if(task.isSuccessful()) {} // you have this code in your last bit of code
else{}                     // you have this in your code already
```

(

you currently have the code

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "registration not performed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

( it is pretty much the last line in the code you provided) but you should replace it with:

```
try {
    throw task.getException();
} catch(FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException e) {
    // email already in use
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Email already taken!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

So **you do not need to check if an email exists yourself** because Firebase will automatically throw an exception and then you can for example display a toast.

Comment: How can I check if the exception (the parameter e) contains the exception of the email that collide?

Comment: My third line does that. The 4th and 5th line will get called if there is an "FirebaseAuthUserCollisoinException". So you don't need to check extra. The part "catch{...}" will only get called if there is a "FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException".

Comment: So to answer your question the "catch(FirebaseUserCollisionException e){}" will get called only if e is the email collision exception.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that `fetchSignInMethodsForEmail` is asynchronous but you call it as if it is synchronouse. Turn your function into a Future / async call that returns `true` or `false`. Othervise your code continues without awaiting the `onComplete` so the value is always `false`.